# How to upload image to Google Drive using MIT APP Inventor II

Tags: app-inventor

I'm trying to upload selected image by MIT App Inventor II. What I did is to download an extension which encodes image to base64 coding, and then call Web1 to address Google App Script. Actually, what I did is just follow an YouTube channel, but somehow it does not work.

```
function doPost(e) {
  
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
  
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data,e.parameters.mimetype,e.parameters.filename);
  
  var folderid = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.folderid);
  
  DriveApp.getFileById(folderid).createFile(blob);
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your File Successfuly Uploaded");
   
}
```

[image: This is App Inventor 2 blocks]

Comment: have you seen this solution? https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/upload-any-file-to-google-drive-with-ai2

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It may take me several days, will test it.

Comment: It works perfectly. I simply downloaded your .aia and then import to App Inventor 2, made modification on folder ID. Really appreciate.

Comment: One more question for an easier way. I mean the ImagePicker works for select photos. I tried this way, but failed because I can not convert the selected image to base64 string and then send it by url.

Comment: for new questions please start a new thread or do a search in the App Inventor community here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/

Answer (score 2):

Combining with Taifun's Extension. These blocks are confirmed to be able to do as below.

1. Display the ImagePicker selected image on the Image component
2. Encode the ImagePicker selected image to a Base64 string.
3. Send the string to URL (Google App Script)

[image: The code]

Comment: you used the [Base64 Extension](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/free-base-64-extension-file-to-from-base-64/41014?u=taifun) by Juan Antonio...

Comment: Yes and really good.